# What's a visual proof for the expansion of $\tan(A+B)$ and $\tan(A-B)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am looking for a visual proof of the following trig identity: $$\tan(A+B) = \frac{\tan A + \tan B}{1 - \tan A\tan B}.$$ Similarly for $\tan(A-B)$.

Comment: the title doesnt match the question

Comment: It isn't division.It refers to 2 different proofs

Comment: Wikipedia's ["List of Trigonometric Identities"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) entry has [an "Angle sum and difference identities" sub-section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) with a diagram illustrating the angle sum formula for tangent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Note here that $BC=1$.

In the above figure, let $$\frac{BF}{BE}=\frac{AD}{DE}$$

Then,

$$\tan(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{DE}{BE}=\frac{AD}{BF}=\frac{\tan{\alpha}-\tan{\beta}}{1+\tan{\alpha}\tan{\beta}}$$

Comment: Can u provide a more direct proof-this is no different to the geometric proof for sine,cosine

Comment: @user16701 Sorry, I misread the question earlier.

Comment: thnx-just what I was looking for

Comment: This is just great! Did you know it already, or did you think it up yourself?